# How to replace multiple comma separated textual words in columns with categorical code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, replace, categories

Hi have a dataset like this:

```
user     read
Den    Insurance
Den    Utility
Mark   Power;Bonds;Corporates
Mark   Government
Celia  Retail
Celia  Technology;Paper
Celia  Food
```

I have another data set like this:

```
Name            Code
Insurance        1
Utility          2
Power            3
Bond             4
Corporates       5
Government       6
Retail           7
Technology       8
Paper            9
Food             10
```

I want to use these to dataframe and convert the first data as this:

```
user     read                  Code
Den    Insurance                1
Den    Utility                  2
Mark   Power;Bonds;Corporates  3,4,5
Mark   Government               6
Celia  Retail                   7
Celia  Technology;Paper        8,9
Celia  Food                     10
```

How can I do this in Python Dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IIUC

```
d = df1.set_index('Name').Code.astype(str)
df0.assign(Code=[', '.join(map(d.get, s.split(';'))) for s in df0.read])

    user                    read     Code
0    Den               Insurance        1
1    Den                 Utility        2
2   Mark  Power;Bonds;Corporates  3, 4, 5
3   Mark              Government        6
4  Celia                  Retail        7
5  Celia        Technology;Paper     8, 9
6  Celia                    Food       10
```

Comment: Getting this error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Series found

Comment: I can't say.  I don't know exactly how your data was created.

Comment: I will work on it. I think you logic will work. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Hey can this be modified to for the ones that does not have a category code? For example if "Car" comes up and its not there in the list of codes, can we tackle it?

Comment: yes, just use a different callable in the `map`.  Use this instead `df0.assign(Code=[', '.join(map(lambda x: d.get(x, '-1'), s.split(';'))) for s in df0.read])`  This will use `'-1'` when a code doesn't exist in the codes dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `unnesting` here for your first dataframe ,then we just need create the code columns accordingly,and `groupby` `agg`

```
df.read=df.read.str.split(';')
df=unnesting(df,['read'])
df['Code']=df.read.map(df1.set_index('Name').Code)
yourdf=df.astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg({'user':'first','read':';'.join,'Code':','.join})
yourdf
Out[255]: 
    user                    read   Code
0    Den               Insurance      1
1    Den                 Utility      2
2   Mark  Power;Bonds;Corporates  3,4,5
3   Mark              Government      6
4  Celia                  Retail      7
5  Celia        Technology;Paper    8,9
6  Celia                    Food     10
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Comment: Hey can this be modified to for the ones that does not have a category code? For example if "Car" comes up and its not there in the list of codes, can we tackle it?